# Run the script automatically in bootup in freebsd

Tags: shell, truecrypt

I tried to run the script, so that when ever I restart the freebsd, the script should run automatically, I kept that script in /etc/rc.d/ and gave full permissions, it is not executing but it is saying:

> eval: truecrypt not found

but when I am trying to run manually it is been executing.

[image]

I kept the script in one location and password in other location.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script successfully, do a

```
which truecrypt
```

which should give you the full path of the truecrypt executable, then specify that full path in place of your `truecrypt` call. Potentially make sure the file is accessible.